# Display metafield name Shopify

Tags: shopify, liquid

I would like to retrieve metafield names in shopify. I know I can retrieve and display the values stored in a metafield with {{product.metafields.custom.key}} but is there a way to retrieve the name of the metafield as seen in the shopify backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the name in the backend is purely descriptive and can't be access from liquid. You can take a look at this [page](https://shopify.dev/api/liquid/objects#metafield) for all the things you can access on an object's metafields.

Comment: Is this still the case as of July 2023?